# How can I install downloaded 'netbeans' in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04

I am new to ubuntu. I've just downloaded 'netbeans ide 7.3' for linux and 'jdk 7'. but don't know how to install them. please tell me proper step by step procedure on installing these application.

Answer (score 0):

### *For .deb files*

copy the application to home directory.open terminal shortcut->ctrl+alt+t.And type

> dpkg -i application-name.deb

### *For sources such as tar.gz*

1. Extract the archive and copy that folder to home directory.
2. Open terminal and type.

> cd name-of-the-folder

then

> ./configure

in case there is no configure file then use

> ./autogen.sh

and

> make

and

> sudo make install

finally

> sudo ldconfig

Answer (score 0):

1. Extract jdk-7
2. Make netbeans.sh file executable: right-click on file > Properties > Permissions Tab > Allow
3. run the below command on terminal (CTRL+ALT+T):
   `/Path/To/Netbeans-sh-file --javahome /Path/To/jdk-folder`
   Amend the above code according to your pathes
   Press Enter/Return key
4. Waiting... > Customize button > Choose your desires
5. you know ...